# Flask App does not recognize the __init__.py folder and cannot be set to it

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to follow the basic Flask tutorial on their website: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/factory/

After creating the virtual environment (outside the `flaskr` folder) and also `__init__.py` inside of the `flaskr` folder, I activated the virtual environment without problem.

However, if I run the basic Flask App setup commands,

```
set FLASK_APP=flaskr
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

Here is what my directory looks like:

```
test
|flaskr
||__init__.py
|venv
```

I should note that if I do create a `app.py` inside of the test directory, which is where I'm working out of, the Flask setup commands do work, but in later steps of the tutorial, it still doesn't recognize change inside of `__init__.py`, leading me to believe that it isn't recognizing the `flaskr` folder in the first place.

For reference, this is the code in `__init__.py`:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

and this is the code in `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

If I do run it with the `app.py` file in the directory, I *don't* get the

```
* Serving Flask app "flaskr"
* Environment: development
* Debug mode: on
```

part of the message.

Comment: How are you running this? From the command line? What's the working directory? Is that the same directory where the app is?

Comment: I'm running this from the pycharm terminal. The working director is `test`. The `flaskr` folder, `app.py` and `venv` are located in it.

Comment: I use the application factory, but I always declare 'FLASK_APP = app.py' and not as 'flaskr'.  Inside the 'app.py' I import the 'create_app' function and create an app which is run inside the main fuction. This setup always worked for me.

Here the Code for app.py: 
from flaskr import create_app

app = create_app()

if \_\_name__ == '\_\_main__':
    app.run()

Comment: That seemed to work! It's just weird that this is happening when I followed the instructions on the Flask documentation website to the letter.